# Late coming and early goings values are not appearing by powershell code

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file having attendance records. I want a late coming and early going of the employees here is my attendance record csv file name kith.csv

```
Date    Person  Start   End Elapsed
04/03/2023  Tehreem     7:29:43 13:35:27    06h, 05m, 44s
04/03/2023  Irfan   7:59:36 13:34:53    05h, 35m, 17s
04/03/2023  Fatima      7:40:06 13:31:06    05h, 51m, 00s
04/03/2023  Talat   7:43:18 13:17:37    05h, 34m, 19s
04/03/2023  Natasha     7:50:37 13:31:16    05h, 40m, 39s
04/03/2023  Zelma   7:46:18 13:40:52    05h, 54m, 34s
04/03/2023  Maryam  7:42:27 13:30:48    05h, 48m, 21s
04/03/2023  Sania   7:38:31 13:32:21    05h, 53m, 50s
04/03/2023  Qurat   8:00:23 13:31:09    05h, 30m, 46s
04/03/2023  Aliza   7:41:45 13:30:53    05h, 49m, 08s
04/03/2023  Nusrat  7:22:09 13:30:59    06h, 08m, 50s
```

I have this `timetable.xlsx` file data

```
Person  TimeIn  TimeOut
-----------------------
Tehreem 7:00 AM 2:30 PM
Aliza   7:00 AM 2:30 PM
Ambreen 7:00 AM 2:30 PM
Amna    7:00 AM 2:30 PM
Arif    7:00 AM 2:30 PM
maryam  7:00 AM 2:30 PM
moona   7:00 AM 2:30 PM
```

Here is my powershell script

```
# Load the attendance records from the CSV file
$attendanceRecords = Import-Csv -Path "F:\att new\kith1.csv"

# Load the employee timetable from the XLSX file
$employeeTimetable = Import-Excel -Path "F:\att new\timetable.xlsx"

# Create an empty array to store the late comings and early goings
$results = @()

# Loop through each attendance record
foreach ($record in $attendanceRecords) {
    $person = $record.Person
    $start = [DateTime]::ParseExact($record.Start, "h:mm tt", $null)
    $end = [DateTime]::ParseExact($record.End, "h:mm tt", $null)

    # Get the expected time in and time out for the employee
    $timetable = $employeeTimetable | Where-Object { $_.Person -eq $person }
    $timeIn = [Datetime]::ParseExact($timetable.TimeIn, "h:mm tt", $null)
    $timeOut = [Datetime]::ParseExact($timetable.TimeOut, "h:mm tt", $null)

    # Debugging: check if the timetable data is being loaded correctly
    Write-Host "Person: $person, TimeIn: $timeIn, TimeOut: $timeOut"

    # Check if the employee was late
    $lateBy = ""
    if ($start -gt $timeIn) {
        $lateTime = ($start - $timeIn).ToString("hh:mm")
        $lateBy = $lateTime
    }

    # Check if the employee left early
    $earlyBy = ""
    if ($end -lt $timeOut) {
        $earlyTime = ($timeOut - $end).ToString("hh:mm")
        $earlyBy = $earlyTime
    }

    # Debugging: check the values of $start, $end, $timeIn, and $timeOut
    Write-Host "Start: $start, End: $end, TimeIn: $timeIn, TimeOut: $timeOut"

    # Add the attendance record to the results
    $attendanceRecord = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Date = $record.Date
        Person = $person
        Start = $record.Start
        End = $record.End
        Elapsed = $record.Elapsed
        LateBy = $lateBy
        EarlyBy = $earlyBy
    }

    $results += $attendanceRecord
}

# Sort the results by date and person
$results = $results | Sort-Object -Property Date, Person

# Export the results to a CSV file
$results | Export-Csv -Path "F:\att new\complete1.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This is the result I get:

```
Date    Person  Start   End Elapsed LateBy  EarlyBy
-------------------------------------------------------------------
04/01/2023  Arif    10:08:36    10:08:45    00h, 00m, 09s    hours,  minutes,  seconds  
04/01/2023  Reema   9:59:44     12:34:14    02h, 34m, 30s    hours,  minutes,  seconds  
04/03/2023  Aliza   7:41:45     13:30:53    05h, 49m, 08s    hours,  minutes,  seconds  
04/03/2023  Ambreen 7:46:12     13:41:04    05h, 54m, 52s    hours,  minutes,  seconds
```

Comment: You haven't told us what isn't working.  Take some time to explain what you expect to see as results and what you are actually seeing. 
(As an aside, you are misinterpreting 12hr time.  In the first record, 13:35 is actually 1:35pm  not 2:35pm).

Comment: @uSlackr thanks for your reply i am getting this output  ```Date Person Start End Elapsed LateBy EarlyBy
04/01/2023 Arif  10:08:36 10:08:45 00h, 00m, 09s  hours,  minutes,  seconds 
04/01/2023 Reema  9:59:44 12:34:14 02h, 34m, 30s  hours,  minutes,  seconds 
04/03/2023 Aliza  7:41:45 13:30:53 05h, 49m, 08s  hours,  minutes,  seconds 
04/03/2023 Ambreen  7:46:12 13:41:04 05h, 54m, 52s  hours,  minutes,  seconds 
``` while i want to get late time hours minuts and seconds value, it is only passing the strings in lateby column. i  have also updated the question about my results which i got

Comment: Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: -Theo i tried to format my question but it given me error in red that "it seems you have a script in your question etc" while kindly check my question and reply if you can fix the issue, as i am not getting my expected result please help

Comment: You use ToString() method .  Should be: ToString("hh:mm") without backslashes.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the reply.. can you please update my code so that i can fix my issue. i am new in coding and no such idea to fix this issue

Comment: @jdweng i have updated my code as per your suggestion also this updated edited in question. but still not getting values in lateby and earlyby columns please help

Comment: is there anyone can help me to solve my issue please

Comment: i am waiting for the solution any one can help me?